# How to implement Spring Security "Digest Authentication"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Can any one please tell me how can I once authenticate my client application with Spring Security "Digest Authentication" and maintain that session until log-out. 
My client is not a form base one it was Rest base one, that mean I want to authenticate my client with Rest request and maintain the session for some transaction and log-out with client's Rest base request. Thanks.

Comment: Client connection for Digest auth is left to the developer own implementation, here's a working sample validated on Spring using my Java client implementation for Digest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750652/2073804

Answer (score 2):

Naturally Web Services are not implemented session based, so you might weant to hand over ther credential to the server at each request. You can easily disable sessions in the namespace of spring security.

For digit authentication please have a look at the manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html#digest-processing-filter

Comment: Hi Philipp Hügelmeyer! Many thanks for your answer, I will looking to that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Philipp Hügelmeyer! Is there any way to accomplish this with token base "spring security authentication"? thanks.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html#remember-me-hash-token

Comment: Hi Philipp Hügelmeyer! Thanks a lot, I will try this out.