# Jena 4 connection to Virtuoso

Tags: java, jena, virtuoso, java-http-client

How can I access authenticated Virtuoso OpenSource *SPARQL 1.1. graph store protocol* through Jena 4? I am facing this problem after having upgraded my codebase from Jena 3 (Apache HttpClient) to Jena 4 (JDK11 HttpClient):

- JDK11 HttpClient [does not seem to support digest authentication](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8285888)
- Virtuoso OpenSource [does not seem to support basic authentication](https://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideSPARQLEndpoints) (but [supports digest authentication](https://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtGraphProtocolCURLExamples))

I am thinking about the following directions to solve the issue:

- implement complete digest authentication challenge in JDK11 HttpClient. As a starting point I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264239/digest-authentication-java-net-http-httpclient).
- connect to Virtuoso using [Virtuoso Jena driver](https://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider)
- switch to another http library (and possibly abandon Jena here)

Since all the options are non-trivial (either in efforts or in impact on the codebase) I would be glad to hear any other suggestions how to go forward. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Digest authentication isn't great. https and basic auth is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Jena applies digest authentication if the challenge response asks for it.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/sparql-apis/http-auth.html#jdk-httpclientauthenticator

This is separate from use of JDK HttpClient.

Jena can also be apply digest authentication on a connection in case 401 (challenge response) isn't given but instead only 403 is. This shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Andy, completely missed this part of doc as I wasn't even expecting Jena to handling it. Your answer did help!